# Adding logo to community template

Tags: community, customer-community, page-template

Is it possible to add a logo to the out-of-box community templates Salesforce provides besides "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce" (the long-standing customer portal/communities template that looks like standard salesforce)?

I tried adding it using the Community Builder and Site.com Studio, but have not been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible via Site.com Studio. You have to import the logo as in image, right click on the destination container, pick "Add Page Elements", and choose the uploaded logo.

[image: Site.com Studio logo addition]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added it in the Community setup? Customize-->Communities-->All Communities-->Manage communities. Administration-->Branding.  Is that not working for you or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: `Branding` is only available with `Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce` template which I don't want to use. I'm looking for the ability to add a logo to other templates.

Comment: Actually it looks like you can add a logo with Summer '15. Here is the link: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_networks_enhanced_branding_editor.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say Spring '15.

Comment: As far as I can see, that utility only allows you to upload an image for the purposes of creating an appropriate color palette.  It does NOT allow you to upload an image for display as a logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by using a CSS Override. This can be accomplished within the Community Builder on Napili.